# App's Permission Request XML not filled when accessing appinv.aspx again

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to add an app to SharePoint and change the permissions it has. My problem is that I don't see the permissions after I have added them.
Here is my work flow:

1. Add the app using [...]/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
2. Go to [...]/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx, look up the app, fill in the Permission Request XML box and click create.
3. Go to [...]/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx again and look up the app.

After step three I would expect to see the Permission Request XML box being filled with the values I just entered, but it is empty.

Is this how it is supposed to be, or am I missing something?

The following snippet is what I enter in the permission box:

```
  <AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Permission Request XML box is always empty, even when you have previously added permissions. Unfortunately it works this way, i was also wondering in the beginning. When you add permissions, they are assigned to the app, but are not shown later.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Do you have any documentation on this? I haven't been able to find any thing about this behaviour.

Comment: I also didn't find any official documentation on this, but I have registered a few apps and it always works this way. The permissions are not shown, but the app can access the needed resources.